# Should I use separate branches when hosting at heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I want to upload the following project to heroku: https://github.com/eranbetzalel/tick-logger.

You've probably noticed that it doesn't contain any "heroku files" (Procfile, different configs, etc...).

I want to create the following configuration for my local repository:

- heroku branch - will contain "heroku files".
- master branch - will only contain the source code (no heroku stuff).

My plan is to regularly push the local heroku branch to heroku remote repository (to its master branch) and to push the local master branch to GitHub remote repository (to its master branch).

Does that make sense?

Any suggestion for better practices are highly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a good idea.

It's best to be explicit with your project -- usually that means making it easier for other developers to figure out how your stuff works.

With Heroku, you don't really need to add much to your project, just a dependency file, and a Procfile (usually).

I'd vote in favor of including those files directly at the top-level to avoid future confusion.

I can't really see the benefit of keeping them separate.